# select all selected index in all checkedlistbox vb

Tags: vb.net

i want to save all the selected index in all checkedlistbox that i have in the form but nothing happens when i clicked my submit button

```
Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdSubmit.Click
    Dim str As String
    For Each c As Control In Me.tabPage1.Controls
        If TypeOf c Is CheckedListBox Then
            str = CType(c, CheckedListBox).SelectedIndex
            ListBox2.Items.Add(str)
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

- the code above now has been edited thanks to mr.iBener for giving me the idea

Comment: Maybe your `CheckedListBox` controls are in another container, like a panel, not your form?

Comment: the CheckedListBox are inside tcExam TabControl control and i did edit the above code , but nothing still happens. I cant figure how it cant return a string.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint inside the if typeof section, does it get hit?

Comment: well i just figured that i cant get values in tabcontrol  but in tabpages. Now do i have to copy this code for each tabpage that i have?